# Verificar dados antes de usar como elemento de array

Tags: c#, .net, array, range

[No chat foi perguntado algo sobre validação de entrada de dados](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45554591#45554591) para evitar erro de pegar fora da faixa permitida. Achei a pergunta interessante e pena que não foi postada aqui, estou postando:

```
public static T[] ReplaceRange<T>(this T[]input, T[] replacement, int start) {
    for (int i = start; i < input.Length; i++) {
        T replacementItem = replacement[i - start];
        input[i] = replacementItem;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Como evitar o erro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pontos de interesse:

- Contratos
- Erros de programação são resolvidos consertando-os
- Algumas reorganizações
- Existe coisa pronta que funciona melhor

Existem algumas formas, eu tenho gostado de usar [contratos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ele tem algumas desvantagens, mas em geral ajuda e deveria ser usado mais, o .NET usa o tempo todo em seus códigos. Se não gostar dele é só mudar para um `if` e lançar uma exceção (é o mesmo que o `Requires()` faz internamente na maioria dos casos, mas tem alguns que ele poderá ser retirado da execução, veja abaixo). Muda alguma coisa? Não muito, apenas que o erro é mais específico, e isso tem implicações positivas, mas pode mudar algo importante.

Uma outra possibilidade é usar um `Assert()` que pode ser garantidamente desligado, o que pode ser uma boa, afinal o erro `Out of Bounds` é erro de programação e a única solução possível é consertar o erro, a única coisa que podemos fazer é garantir que um código bem testado dê o erro em tempo de desenvolvimento e se tiver algum erro na chamada também tenha o problema resolvido. Se tiver certeza que o erro não acontece mais o `Assert()` não vai para produção, já o `Requires()` pode ir, mas ao mesmo tempo pode ser mais seguro se não tiver tanta certeza assim.

Na versão atual do Visual Studio essa retirada do `Requires()` não é automática, precisa instalar e configurar o uso de análise e retirada automática dos contratos.

Outra possibilidade é fazer nada, afinal erro de programação se resolve e não tenta contornar, e eu tenho optado por isso. Mas pode fazer algo assim:

Os nomes dos parâmetros do exemplo não são bons, são enganosos.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var item in ReplaceRange(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 2)) WriteLine(item);
    }
    public static T[] ReplaceRange<T>(T[] source, T[] destination, int start) {
        Requires(start >= 0, "O índice de início não pode ser menor que zero");
        Requires(start < source.Length, "O índice de início não pode ser maior que o fim do array");
        Requires(destination.Length >= source.Length - start, "O índice de início não pode ser maior que o que cabe");
        for (int i = start, j = 0; i < source.Length; i++, j++) destination[i] = source[j];
        return destination;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gRnyB7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ewkrrI). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Replace.cs).

Não vou colocar para rodar *online* porque esses ambientes são limitados, a grande vantagem é quando a ferramenta ajuda, o Visual Studio por exemplo pode informar de problemas durante o desenvolvimento, ou tem ferramentas que geram testes para você baseado no contrato encontrado dentro do método (preciso até me atualizar porque mudou desde a última vez que usei).

Mas pode simplificar isso e usar o [`Array.Copy()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que já existe no .NET. Se quiser só faça um *wrap* simples para considerar apenas o início da fonte e ele preencher sozinho o início do destino e o tamanho da cópia.

Postei mais com intuito de mostrar que tem alternativas, algumas que poucos conhecem, tem maneiras de resolver sem fazer nada no código e há maneiras de usar o que já tem pronto que será bem mais rápido porque fará uma cópia [*blittable*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blit), até onde dá.

Comment: O que esse `Requires(bool, string)` faz? Achei interessante.

Comment: Verifica se o argumento está ok.